# Is this Cambridge Dictionary example of "felicitate" valid?

Tags: meaning

Cambridge dictionary defines ["felicitate"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/felicitate) as

> To praise someone and say that you approve of or are pleased about a
>   special or unusual achievement.

Then the  first usage example given is:

> Modern developments in collecting language data, including
>   taperecordings, have felicitated the growth of corpus analysis and
>   increased the objectivity of this work.

Is this example valid?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo (***felicitate*** for ***facilitate***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am also voting to close for the same reason.

Comment: While I have no problem with closing this question, it makes sense, I would just like to note that if the answer to a similar question was instead *yes*, the question would not be closed. But I got my answer anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No: in the example, there is a typo; it should really be *facilitate*. So Cambridge just searches a couple of corpora and displays arbitrary instances of the word in question, without checking them at all. (The Oxford English Dictionary has real examples of its entries, which are actually checked.)

Comment: You can submit corrections to Cambridge, though; I just submitted a ticket to the effect that this is not an example of the dictionary entry under which it appears.

Comment: I doubt that Cambridge haven't got a filter for false positives. Obviously it's imperfect, and Janus is to be felicitated on facilitating a correction.

Comment: Given this example, this then seems a natural mistaken conflation: "facilitate" and "felicitate".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Well done.

Answer (score 2):

No. Modern developments praising the growth of corpus analysis doesn't make sense. One *felicitates* someone, not something. This is probably a typo of [facilitate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/facilitate):

> to make something possible or easier:

In this case, collecting language data in better ways would indeed make (the growth of) corpus analysis more feasible.

The feature you are using collects examples of actual usage from elsewhere, but either human or algorithmic error creeps in from time to time. I suggest flagging it with the comment function next to the entry and moving on.

Comment: This answer has already been given.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: There are significant differences. For one thing, this answer explains why it cannot be *felicitate* in the example given.

Comment: At the time I posted from my phone, an answer was not yet visible. After posting and seeing the answer, I kept it up. Why? The other answer also addresses the question well, but as Cerberus points out, it does not explain why *felicitate* does not work or why *facilitate* does.